# Wxpython How to change the colour of Gauge Progress bar in windows

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, wxpython

I am designing a software in Python using WxPython as GUI in Windows.I want to change the default colour  of Gauge Progress bar in my application.
Please help...
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like SetForegroundColour or SetBackgrounColour, but since the gauge wraps the native widget, I'm not sure that those will have any effect. Fortunately, there is a generic gauge widget called PyGauge: wx.lib.agw.pygauge

I don't think it's quite as pretty as the native one, but you can definitely change the color. There are a couple examples of PyGauge in the wxPython demo package.